# Is it possible to sort your email in Gmail by something other than the date received?

Tags: gmail, sorting

I want to sort my email in Gmail by the sender, rather than the date received, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to sort by sender? Are you looking for one sender in particular? Why not just search for them?

Comment: @x3ka - I want to be able to read through email from a group of senders, but I want to see each sender's emails co-located in the list rather than ordered by date.

Comment: `function sort(){$mails = jQuery(document).xpath("//tr[td/div/span[@email]]");  $mails.tsort("td.yX>div.yW>span",{attr:'email'}); }` works on the UI only. Selection is creating problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not yet. This feature is still on suggest list of feature for Gmail.

[Suggest a feature for Gmail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs)

Comment: The list of features suggestions to be voted was removed so each user should type their suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to do this, one way is to download your messages into Thunderbird, for example, and sort them there.  Google has a philosophical objection to sorting (except for reverse chronological order by last activity, of course) and is unlikely to implement this anytime soon.