# Sort Gmail by Date?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, javascript, sorting, greasemonkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to sort your email in GMail by something other than the date received?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/222/is-it-possible-to-sort-your-email-in-gmail-by-something-other-than-the-date-recei)

Is there any way to sort Gmail by date in the web interface? The priority inbox is nice, but I would still like to have the feature of having the oldest messages on top. A Chrome extension or GreaseMonkey script that works would be fine.

[image: inbox]

Comment: You mean you want the Classic view instead of the priority inbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click on **View all** (in your case) or **...more**
2. Click on **1-50 of XXX**
3. Click on **Oldest**

In some cases it doesn't work and I don't know why. Also, it doesn't work in *Priority Inbox* view, you have to go to each category - *Important, Starred, Everything else* - to be able to sort by Newest/Oldest.

[image]