# Gmail inbox: older emails first

Tags: gmail, google-chrome-extensions, greasemonkey, userscripts

Gmail puts the newer emails first as follows:

- anita@openmailbox.com | Dogs issue | **19:40**
- pepito@hotmail.com | Important facts from Jupiter | 14:03
- juanito@gmail.com | You coming? | 09:25

Everything else (already seen email)

- tsstss@openmailbox.com | Dinosaurs still exists! | 17:13
- jaja@hotmail.com | Yep or Nope | 14:08
- blabla@gmail.com | Whatever? | 09:27

---

**I think it is better to start reading the oldest non-seen emails:**

- juanito@gmail.com | You coming? | **09:25**
- pepito@hotmail.com | Important facts from Jupiter | 14:03
- anita@openmailbox.com | Dogs issue | 19:40

**Everything else** (already seen email, same order: **first the newer email**)

- tsstss@openmailbox.com | Dinosaurs still exists! | 17:13
- jaja@hotmail.com | Yep or Nope | 14:08
- blabla@gmail.com | Whatever? | 09:27

Is it possible? How?

---

**UPDATE** (from comments)

Gmail does not have an option for that. However, maybe there are some [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) **scripts** able to do that. Or some Chrome or Firefox extension.

Comment: You cannot change the way Gmail sorts messages.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Sort Gmail by Date?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19729/354)

Comment: OK @AlE. I wonder if there is some javascript script somewhere though.

Comment: Maybe. Your question is still on-topic, although you can't do what you want with Gmail all by itself. A third-party client is an option (Thunderbird, et al.), too. My JS-Foo isn't up to the task.

Comment: Maybe we should move this question to stackoverflow. Or maybe there is some kind of greasemonkey script which already does that! :/

Comment: This wouldn't be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the sort order in Gmail but some other tools like IMAP and POP desktop clients have that feature.

The built-alternative to changing the sort order, is to use Gmail search (see [1]). It includes search constraints. Also, could be used the search operators "before", "after", "newer" and "older".

From [2]

> Example: after:2004/04/16 before:2004/04/18  Meaning: Messages sent
>   between April 16, 2004 and April 18, 2004.*
>   *More precisely: Messages sent after 12:00 AM (or 00:00) April 16, 2004 and before April 18, 2004.

**References**
[1] [Search in Gmail - Gmail help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6593?hl=en)
[2] [Advanced search - Gmail help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

Gmail allows one to jump to the oldest emails for searches or labels (http://www.scottgreenstone.com/2015/05/gmail-how-to-sort-by-oldest-or-newest.html).

However, I have been unable to find a way to make the oldest page the default (eg. using GreaseMonkey or a browser extension).  The closest seems to be a comment by LifeH2O ([Is it possible to sort your email in Gmail by something other than the date received?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/222/is-it-possible-to-sort-your-email-in-gmail-by-something-other-than-the-date-rece?lq=1)) where he states:

> *function sort(){$mails = jQuery(document).xpath("//tr[td/div/span[@email]]");
>   $mails.tsort("td.yX>div.yW>span",{attr:'email'}); } works on the UI
>   only. Selection is creating problem*